Duty Cycle Clamp
The application notes of phase shift full bridge converter states that ''the delay times need to achieve ZVS for MOSFETs can as a duty cycle clamp''. They have a calculation as given below.
The typical duty cycle of this application is 0.66 during normal operation. I couldn't imagine or understand the meaning of this Dclamp=94% when delay (dead time) is introduced to get ZVS. What does Dclamp mean?

Source: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_Texas-Instruments-TI-UCC28950PWR_C91312.pdf

Wasn't this exact question posted last week?

In the context of the UCC28950 phase-shifted full-bridge converter, Dclamp refers to the upper limit of the duty cycle when accounting for delays introduced to ensure Zero Voltage Switching (ZVS). The delay, also known as dead time, is necessary for achieving ZVS, which helps to minimize switching losses by turning on the MOSFETs when their voltage is zero.
In normal operation, the duty cycle might be 66% (as in your case), but when dead time is introduced to accommodate ZVS, the effective duty cycle can increase beyond this, up to a theoretical limit—this is the Dclamp value. A Dclamp of 94% suggests that the maximum achievable duty cycle, after including the ZVS dead time, can reach as high as 94% of the total switching period, rather than the typical 66% during regular operation without dead time adjustments.
This is a necessary tradeoff to balance efficient switching with ensuring that the MOSFETs experience ZVS, thereby improving system efficiency.
